# Button FontWeight doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, fonts, windows-phone-7.1

I try to set fontWeight of an Button but font weight is still the same.

My button

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton"
    Grid.Row="3"
    FontWeight="Bold"
    Content="something"
    Padding="16,10,12,12"
    FontSize="24"
    Background="White"
    Foreground="#400000"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't have a font weight assigned to the button...

Comment: What?? I don't see the `FontWeight` property anywhere in your XAML.

Comment: ohh, sorry I paste wrong code, its edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the `FontWeight` you have to actually set the FontWeight.
See below where I've added this property to your code and set it to "Thin":

For WP7.x any page level style will override what you're doing explicitly so you need to do a little bit more work:

```
    <Button x:Name="MyButton"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Padding="16,10,12,12"
            FontSize="24"
            Background="White"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" >
            <TextBlock Text="something"
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" 
                       Foreground="#400000"
                       FontWeight="Thin" />
        </Button>
```

Note that I've had to set a style for the content and then applied a FontWeight which will override what's in the style.

This (simpler version) will work for WP8

```
        <Button x:Name="MyButton"
                FontWeight="Thin"
                Grid.Row="3"
                Content="something"
                Padding="16,10,12,12"
                FontSize="24"
                Background="White"
                Foreground="#400000"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
```

Comment: It doesn do anything, in designer window I see that change but when I run it on my phone, font weight is unchanged

Comment: @Earlgray Sorry, I only tested for WP8. It's different for WP7.X (which I should have spotted that you'd specified). I've updated the answer and tested in the VS designer and emulator.